# Localize Windows Forms and Change the Language at Runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, localization, resources

I'm following this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=174 to Localize Windows Forms and Change the Language at Runtime. Everything works fine for label/button:textbox but for `Datagridview`it's not working. When i check the resource file, the french version and the default version text is there but when i execute it the last version was loading..it's not not showing the default english version in when i select from list box.

How can i chnage the datagridview header text at run time using the mechnaism given in the above link???
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Roy Dictus: How do i change the datagridview header text at run time using the mechnaism given in the above link???

Comment: Is it bound. ie.e name and value are column names in the underlying datasource?

Comment: Can't you just do grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Whatever" ?

Comment: @Roy Dictus: I'm thinking, it would be better to do it through resource file.

Comment: @ Tony Hopkinson: In the design view, i can see both fench and english version separately but when i execute it i just see only one version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code can only find controls that are added to the form's Controls collection.  But a DataGridView column does not get added like that, it gets added to the DataGridView control.  You'll need to improve the posted code so that it also iterates columns of any DGV it finds.  Like this:

```
    private void ChangeLanguage(string lang) {
        var ci = new CultureInfo(lang);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
            ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType());
            resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, ci);
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(DataGridView)) {
                var dgv = (DataGridView)c;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns) {
                    resources.ApplyResources(col, col.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ Hans Passant: yep, it works for me too. The mistake i did, it was i assigned different data property names...Thank you very much.